# How wide and long can you make a web page. Is there a limit?

Tags: html

I am interested in making a table in HTML and it will be big.

Is there anything that limits just how far to the right or how far down I can go on any particular page ?

Comment: What if scroll-er is added ?? Question is what you want and what you tried for this?

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format ??? What ? .. it's a fair question and one I needed an answer too ... ?? Question Nazis here I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.
For optimizing to different monitors / devices read about Responsive & Adaptive design (or use javascript for ie6).

Answer (score 1):

The only limitation is the hardware of the device that will display it. I don't mean the screen size. I mean the CPU and RAM of the device, that's your limit. The bigger your page is, the more CPU and RAM it will need.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, there is no limit on width and height for a web page. But in the view of a designer. I think making your page too big is not a good idea. It'll make your web page has bad "look and feel". Instead of that, you should try using paging to make the "look and feel" way better

Answer (score 0):

No there is not a limit on length or width.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit in either dimension.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limit for height or width. But I think it depends on **whether you define height/width of a component in px or %**. Also, it depends on the size of your content.